# Unix-- get 3rd field sum from a file

Tags: unix, sh

I have a file with 5 fields with 10 rows of data, now i want to get the sum of all 3rd fields in a file.

Sample:

```
a,b,1,4,5
c,d,3,4,6
f,h,4,y,j

O/p: 1+3+4= 8
```

My solution is cut the 3rd field using cut command and write it to another file and then using awk to calculate the sum.

Is there any alternative way?

Comment: `awk -F, '{print $3};END{print "all done"}' file` will give you a clue. You **can** do it all in 1 call to awk, don't use a pipe. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is all you need:

```
awk -F, '{ sum += $3 } END {print sum}' filename
```

Comment: And to get the OP's exact output: `awk -F, '{printf "%s%s", sep, $3; sep="+"; sum+=$3} END {print "=", sum}' file`